# Hiding multiple views with same id

Tags: android, textview, visibility, android-view

I have a xml file that contains four views with the same id.

Now I want to hide all these views together at once.

So I wrote the code:

```
TextView maintitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fieldheading);
maintitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

where my xml has all four views with id:

```
 android:id="@+id/fieldheading"
```

But this doesn't hides any view.

Is it necessary to give different id for each view in order to hide them.
Doesn't it be hidden at once ?

**NOTE:** All four views are in different LinearLayouts of xml file.

Comment: I think Android gets confused when you have more id which are identical. It wants UNIQUE ids.

Comment: Agreed. You cannot assign same id to multiple views in the same layout. You can place all of them into one single master container and hide that though (if your layout permits such placement, naturally)

Answer (score 0):

Put four different ids, and use the hide code four times. Actually you should create a `hideTextView(TextView tv);` and call it four times for clean purposes.

Not sure if it is possible to hide textviews like you say, but it is definitely wrong.

Comment: Agreed. Giving different ids will always work. But what if you have many textviews to hide or suppose consider a case where you are creating lot more dynamic textviews in a loop and want to hide them all at some place. Probably, thinking all should be hide at once.

Comment: You can set them a tag and then check and hide items with that tag.